# Shared assembly is duplicated on build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mef, projects-and-solutions

Probably a stupidly simple question but I can't seem to find an answer online.

I have a solution with projects A, B and C.

Projects B and C have a reference set to Project A.

Projects B and C have their output path set to a subdirectory of Project A's output directory.

Project B and C have a reference path set up to look in Project A's output directory.

The problem is, Project A is getting placed in Project B and C's output directory as well as in it's own directory. This is causing problems with using MEF unless I manually delete the duplicated assembly.

I'm getting this structure:

```
[OutputPath]
    ProjectA.exe
    [Subdirectory]
        ProjectB.dll
        ProjectC.dll
        ProjectA.exe
```

How can I prevent Project B and C from rebuilding Project A in their own output directory so I end up with this directory structure after each build?

```
[OutputPath]
    ProjectA.exe
    [Subdirectory]
        ProjectB.dll
        ProjectC.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to look at the properties for the references themselves and set "Copy Local" to false.

Answer (score 0):

remove reference to A in B and C :)

Comment: But then B and C won't build, they use classes from Project A. I just want to figure out a way where B and C will look for Project A in the reference path I setup before automatically rebuilding it themselves. I can delete the duplicate and everything works, I just don't want it to be built in the first place since there's already a valid copy in the reference path.